# error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of UserListModule, but itself has errors 29 export class DataGridModule { }

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-upgrade, angular-migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWhzN.png)```
Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/shared/shared-form.module.ts:84:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of PrivateLinesDetailsModule, but itself has errors

84 export class SharedFormModule { }

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/datagrid.module.ts:29:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of trunkGroupsModule, but itself has errors

29 export class DataGridModule { }
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of BCPUserPriorityModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of ExtensionsLinesModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of GroupDirectoryModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MGTrunkModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MOHLinesDetailsModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MediaGatewaysModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MonitoringModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of OCLinesDetailsModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of PBXSharedLinesModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of PrivateLinesDetailsModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of SoftwareImageDetailsModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of TabEntryModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of TreeAvailableToAssignModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/tree-data.module.ts:22:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of trunkGroupsModule, but itself has errors

22 export class TreeDataModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xmenu/view/ControlIconBar.ts:49:17 - error NG1010: template must be a string
Value is a reference to 'template1'.

49       template: template1,
~~~~~~~~~

src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xmenu/view/ControlIconBar.ts:45:30
45   private compileToComponent(template1: string,parentRef:ControlIconBar): Promise<ComponentFactory> {
~~~~~~~~~
Reference is declared here.

Error: src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xmenu/view/ControlIconBar.ts:73:22 - error NG6001: The class 'DynamicComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'DynamicModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

73       declarations: [DynamicComponent]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~m

src/app/UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xmenu/view/ControlIconBar.ts:52:11
52     class DynamicComponent implements OnDestroy{
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'DynamicComponent' is declared here.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

i see above error

```
while migrating version 12 to 13 version of angular i have been facing above issue and tried multiple solutions like below

I have tried adding below code on both tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.json files

# **"angularCompilerOptions": {
#     "enableIvy": false,
#     "strictTemplates": false
#   }**


made lazy routing of my app-routing.module.ts wherever loadchildren is avialble including remaing routes of my application whereever existing

# 
# path: 'HardwareDeployment',
# loadChildren: () => import('src/app/logicarc/com/ulo/hereit/modules/deployed/hardware.module').then(x => x.HardwareDeploymentModule)
# }**


package.json includes below versions 
# **"dependencies": {
#     "@angular/animations": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/common": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/core": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/forms": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
#     "@angular/localize": "^9.1.0",
#     "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/platform-server": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/router": "^13.1.2",
# 
# 
# "devDependencies": {
#     "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/cli": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.2",
#     "@angular/language-service": "^13.1.2",
# **

In angular.json made below change but not useful
# **"aot": false, "buildOptimizer": false,** ...

cross checked component declaration in imports: [] instead of declarations: [] but have no issues have correct code too

have tried clearing npm cache force and tried running ng serve again
restarted Visual stuudio code multiple times
sometimes i even made deletion of node modules folder and tried npm install even it didn't work
tried deleting .angular cache folder from root folder and tried running but not useful.

i have tried on node version 14.17.2 and currently on 16.20.0 but same issue persists again ..

can some one let me know what to do
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refine your questions to a minimum reproducible example. Terse questions of limited scope have a better chance of getting answers that are useful to you and the community as a whole.